# Proving the interval in which a solution is valid

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

**Question:** Verify that both $y_1(x) = 1-x$ and $y_2(x)= \frac{-x^2}{4}$ are solutions of the initial value problem $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-x+(x^2+4y)^\frac{1}{2}}{2},  \ \ \ y(2)=-1$$
and determine where these solutions are valid

**My attempt:**

The first part is fairly straightforward however am I having trouble getting the answer for the second part of the question. The solution says that it is valid for all x.

However if $$f(x,y) =\frac{-x+(x^2+4y)^\frac{1}{2}}{2} $$

Then $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x,y)= \frac{-1+2(x^2+4y)^{-\frac{1}{2}}}{2}$$

And for the solution to be valid doesn't $x^2\ge-4y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but remember that $y = y_1(x)$ and $y = y_2(x)$ respectively.So, in the inequality $$x^2 > -4y$$replace $y$ with $y_1(x)$ and $y_2(x)$ to check that the ineqality holds for all $x$

Comment: How do you check whether the inequality holds? Do you move everything to the right and prove its always greater than 0?

Comment: Yes, that's usually the way to go about it.